# Simple non convex optimization

Tags: non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem. I'd appreciate any tips or directions.

$ \text{minimize }  |x|^2 + |y|^2$

$ \text{subject to } |x-y|^2 \geq 1$

where $|.|$ is the absolute value, and $x$ and $y$ are two complex scalers.

EDITED: The variables are complex

Comment: Draw a little picture of the feasible set in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

$\lvert x - y \rvert^2 \ge 1$ is equivalent to $\lvert x - y \rvert \ge 1$ and is the union of two disjoint "parallel" half-planes.

$\lvert x \rvert^2 + \lvert y \rvert^2$ is the square of the radius of a circle passing through $(x,y)$ centered on the origin.

Comment: What if the variables are complex?